# Regex Capturing Group within a Capture Group

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am searching through a database to find span tags with video information for the purpose of migration.

My regex works well and I can extract all of the information I need for the most part.   The trouble I run into is when the style tag is in a different position than expected.   This throws off the expression and results in about 2/3rds of the captures I would expect.

If I try and nest the style capture group inside the main capture group, it fails to capture anything.   I also tried using negative/positive lookaheads as well, but it only ever works if I make it an optional capture group.   I think the problem is im not nesting it correctly.   Most of the related questions give the answer of a negative lookbehind, but my understanding is that's more of a assertion/quantifier.

So how can I always capture the style tag regardless of its position in the span tag?

Regex flavor is .NET (server side)

I have a [Regexr](https://regexr.com/4f2mv) setup

`/(?<tag><span class='vidly-vid' data-thumb='(?<thumb>http.+\.jpg)'.+aspect-ratio='(?<aspect>\d{1,3}:\d{1,3})'.+sources='\[{"file":.+"(?<src>(?<uri>https:\/\/cf1234.cloudfront\.net\/Vids\/)(?<key>(?<ident>[0-9a-fA-F]{8}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}|[a-z0-9]{6})\/(?<mp4>mp4_1080.mp4|mp4_720.mp4|mp4_480.mp4|mp4_360.mp4|mp4.mp4))).+style='(?<style>.+width: (?<width>.+)px.+height: (?<height>.+)px.+)'.+<\/span>)/gmi`

Sample Data

All of these should match.   The first one does NOT, the other three do.

```
<span class='vidly-vid' data-thumb='https://cf1234.cloudfront.net/Vids/Thumbnails/691DBB43-5EC8-4D57-AF7B-99896D9BD5D1_19127.jpg' data-aspect-ratio='4:3' style='border-width: 0px; width: 352px; height: 240px;' data-sources='[{"file":"https://cf1234.cloudfront.net/Vids/6v1j0a/hls.m3u8","label":"HD"},{"file":"https://cf1234.cloudfront.net/Vids/6v1j0a/mp4_360.mp4","label":"360p SD"}]'>&#160;</span>

<span class='vidly-vid' data-thumb='https://cf1234.cloudfront.net/Vids/Thumbnails/b181cfa5-565d-470a-b93a-2610987bb4da_28142.jpg' data-aspect-ratio='160:117' data-sources='[{"file":"https://cf1234.cloudfront.net/Vids/b181cfa5-565d-470a-b93a-2610987bb4da/hls.m3u8","label":"HD"},{"file":"https://cf1234.cloudfront.net/Vids/b181cfa5-565d-470a-b93a-2610987bb4da/mp4_480.mp4","label":"480p SD"},{"file":"https://cf1234.cloudfront.net/Vids/b181cfa5-565d-470a-b93a-2610987bb4da/mp4_360.mp4","label":"360p SD"},{"file":"https://cf1234.cloudfront.net/Vids/b181cfa5-565d-470a-b93a-2610987bb4da/mp4_720.mp4","label":"720p HD"},{"file":"https://cf1234.cloudfront.net/Vids/b181cfa5-565d-470a-b93a-2610987bb4da/mp4_1080.mp4","label":"1080p HD"}]' style='border-width: 0px; width: 600px; height: 480px;'>&#160;</span>

<table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" style="width:600px">   <tbody>    <tr>     <td><img alt="" src="/content/generator/Course_90016206/Case-10-LMLO_MG_FLAVOR1label.jpg" style="height:497px; width:324px" /></td>     <td><span class='vidly-vid' data-thumb='https://cf1234.cloudfront.net/Vids/Thumbnails/b2a7cbd3-5d31-49a5-bf89-aef0cf9f7414_28142.jpg' data-aspect-ratio='146:225' data-sources='[{"file":"https://cf1234.cloudfront.net/Vids/b2a7cbd3-5d31-49a5-bf89-aef0cf9f7414/hls.m3u8","label":"HD"},{"file":"https://cf1234.cloudfront.net/Vids/b2a7cbd3-5d31-49a5-bf89-aef0cf9f7414/mp4_480.mp4","label":"480p SD"},{"file":"https://cf1234.cloudfront.net/Vids/b2a7cbd3-5d31-49a5-bf89-aef0cf9f7414/mp4_360.mp4","label":"360p SD"},{"file":"https://cf1234.cloudfront.net/Vids/b2a7cbd3-5d31-49a5-bf89-aef0cf9f7414/mp4_720.mp4","label":"720p HD"},{"file":"https://cf1234.cloudfront.net/Vids/b2a7cbd3-5d31-49a5-bf89-aef0cf9f7414/mp4_1080.mp4","label":"1080p HD"}]' style='border-width: 0px; width: 324px; height: 500px;'>&#160;</span></td>    </tr>   </tbody>  </table>

<span class='vidly-vid' data-thumb='https://cf1234.cloudfront.net/Vids/Thumbnails/231913a7-b608-4d8b-9332-64b6840c22f0_28142.jpg' data-aspect-ratio='16:9' data-sources='[{"file":"https://cf1234.cloudfront.net/Vids/231913a7-b608-4d8b-9332-64b6840c22f0/hls.m3u8","label":"HD"},{"file":"https://cf1234.cloudfront.net/Vids/231913a7-b608-4d8b-9332-64b6840c22f0/mp4_480.mp4","label":"480p SD"},{"file":"https://cf1234.cloudfront.net/Vids/231913a7-b608-4d8b-9332-64b6840c22f0/mp4_360.mp4","label":"360p SD"},{"file":"https://cf1234.cloudfront.net/Vids/231913a7-b608-4d8b-9332-64b6840c22f0/mp4_720.mp4","label":"720p HD"},{"file":"https://cf1234.cloudfront.net/Vids/231913a7-b608-4d8b-9332-64b6840c22f0/mp4_1080.mp4","label":"1080p HD"}]' style='border-width: 0px; width: 920px; height: 520px;'>&#160;</span>
```

Comment: Have you tried using a HTML parser?

Comment: Oh my, it must be a real joy to maintain and troubleshoot your regex pattern ;-P (in other words: what the 1st comment said...)

Comment: Linking [the obligatory infamous regex/html answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/120955).

Comment: Wow - I missed that.   Sounds like I should just make the style capture group optional and just guess if its missing since thats the only part im missing.

Comment: Yeah, or you could take a step back and use a series of simple regexes with a little C# to string 'em together, rather than trying to get all the captures in one giant regex. For example, I bet once you've identified the target span you could come up with a regex that works pretty well for grabbing just the style tag out of it.

Comment: Yeah... don't do this. Use something like https://html-agility-pack.net/

Comment: Right - but it just needs to work one time, and its a matter of a string being in one position vs another.    Works fine otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd personally just split up the regex into more manageable chunks, like so:

```
var spanRegex = new Regex(@"<span class='vidly-vid'.+<\/span>");
var attrRegexes = new[]{
    @"data-thumb='(?<thumb>http.+\.jpg)'",
    @"aspect-ratio='(?<aspect>\d{1,3}:\d{1,3})'",
    @"sources='\[{""file"":.+""(?<src>(?<uri>https:\/\/cf1234.cloudfront\.net\/Vids\/)(?<key>(?<ident>[0-9a-fA-F]{8}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}|[a-z0-9]{6})\/(?<mp4>mp4_1080.mp4|mp4_720.mp4|mp4_480.mp4|mp4_360.mp4|mp4.mp4)))",
    @"style='(?<style>.+width: (?<width>.+)px.+height: (?<height>.+)px.+)'",
}
.Select(r => new Regex(r))
.ToList();
var results = inputs.Select(i => spanRegex.Match(i).Value)
    .Select(i => new
    {
        i,
        attributes = 
            from r in attrRegexes
            let match = r.Match(i)
            from g in match.Groups.Cast<Group>().Skip(1)
            select new {g.Name, capture = g.Value}
    });
```

[Linqpad example](http://share.linqpad.net/5utdkf.linq)
[image: LINQPad results]